# Generate Hash of a String that is formed by numbers and letters in Arduino

Tags: encryption, hash, arduino, sha1, arduino-uno

I'm doing a project where I need to randomly generate Hash numbers.

The code has to work as follows.

A random function generates a random number, these numbers are concatenated with a String to then generate the Hash of this String, ie each time a number is generated, the Hash of that number is also generated, this must be looped. To generate the hash I'm using a library called SpritzCipher.

The problem with this code is that it generates the hash of the word "random" instead of the hash of the concatenation of the value with String (salt).

Here is the code I did:

```cpp
#include <SpritzCipher.h>

String salt = "fkllrnjnfd";
int randNumber;
String valorConcat;

void randomico() {
  //Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0)); // Starts the list of random values

  randNumber = random(100); // Draw a number from 0 to 99

  valorConcat = String(randNumber) + salt;

  //Serial.println(valorConcat);  // Sends the value of randNumber to the serial
  delay(500); // espera 500 ms
}


/* Data to input */

const byte testData[12] = {randomico};

/* Test vectors */
/* Data = 'testData' hash test vectors */
const byte testVector[32] =
{ 0xff, 0x8c, 0xf2, 0x68, 0x09, 0x4c, 0x87, 0xb9,
  0x5f, 0x74, 0xce, 0x6f, 0xee, 0x9d, 0x30, 0x03,
  0xa5, 0xf9, 0xfe, 0x69, 0x44, 0x65, 0x3c, 0xd5,
  0x0e, 0x66, 0xbf, 0x18, 0x9c, 0x63, 0xf6, 0x99
};


void testFunc(const byte ExpectedOutput[32], const byte *data, byte dataLen)
{
  byte hashLen = 32; /* 256-bit */
  byte digest[hashLen]; /* Output buffer */
  byte digest_2[hashLen]; /* Output buffer for chunk by chunk API */
  spritz_ctx hash_ctx; /* the CTX for chunk by chunk API */
  unsigned int i;

  /* Print input */
  for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
    Serial.write(data[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  spritz_hash_setup(&hash_ctx);
  /* For easy test: code add a byte each time */
  for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
    spritz_hash_update(&hash_ctx, data + i, 1);
  }
  spritz_hash_final(&hash_ctx, digest_2, hashLen);

  spritz_hash(digest, hashLen, data, dataLen);

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(digest); i++) {
    if (digest[i] < 0x10) { /* To print "0F" not "F" */
      Serial.write('0');
    }
    Serial.print(digest[i], HEX);
  }

  /* Check the output */
  if (spritz_compare(digest, ExpectedOutput, sizeof(digest)) || spritz_compare(digest_2, ExpectedOutput, sizeof(digest_2))) {
    /* If the output is wrong "Alert" */
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH); /* Turn pin LED_BUILTIN On (Most boards have this LED connected to digital pin 13) */
    Serial.println("\n** WARNING: Output != Test_Vector **");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  /* Initialize serial and wait for port to open */
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; /* Wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only */
  }

  /* initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN (Most boards have this LED connected to digital pin 13) as an output */
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("[Spritz spritz_hash*() test]\n");


  /* Data: arcfour */
  testFunc(testVector, testData, sizeof(testData));

  delay(5000); /* Wait 5s */
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: You are hashing `testData`, but you are concatenating strings into `valorConcat`. And `const byte testData[12] = {randomico};` doesn't make sense. You are just initializing it as the address of the `randomico` function. The compiler should have given you a warning.

Comment: Also how do you know, that you are actually hashing the string `"random"`? Your code doesn't print any such string. And your `testVector` is a hash of the string `"arcfour"` and won't match any of the hashes for your random salted strings. Even if you put `arcfour` into `testData`, `testVector` won't match because, the string `"arcfour\0\0\0\0\0"` will be hashed. You should use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`.

Comment: How can I use this algorithm to generate the hash of a String generated by "void random  ()"? Would you know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of your hashing code is just and example of two different options of hashing an array of bytes and comparing it to a known hash.

Since you only need to calculate the hash you only need to call `spritz_hash`.

As for your string generation, a more efficient way would be to use low level C++ functions, since the `String` object is using dynamic memory allocation and that [can cause memory problems](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/).

```cpp
#include <SpritzCipher.h>

#define hex_char(n) ((n) < 10 ? '0' + (n) : 'A' + ((n)-10))

const char salt[] = "fkllrnjnfd";
char string[13] = "";
byte hash[32]; // byte hash
char hash_string[65]; // hex string hash

void randomico(char *string)
{
    int randNumber = random(100); // Draw a number from 0 to 99
    itoa(randNumber, string, 10); // convert int into char array
    strcat(string, salt); // concatenate salt
}

void bytes_to_hexstr(char *string, byte *bytes, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        string[i*2] = bytes[i] < 16 ? '0' : hex_char((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF);
        string[i*2+1] = hex_char(bytes[i] & 0xF);
    }
    string[size*2] = 0;
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);

  randomSeed(analogRead(0)); // Starts the list of random values
}

void loop()
{
    randomico(string); // generate random salted string into 'string' variable
    spritz_hash(hash, 32, (byte*)string, strlen(string)); // hash 'string' into 'hash' variable (hash only the character inside the string not the full char array)
    bytes_to_hexstr(hash_string, hash, 32); // convert byte hash into printable hex string

    // print out string and hash
    Serial.print(string);
    Serial.print(" -> ");
    Serial.println(hash_string);

    delay(1000);
}
```

But if you really want to use `String` you can do it as such:

```cpp
String str = String(random(100))+salt;
spritz_hash(hash, 32, (byte*)str.c_str(), str.length());
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the help.
I just do not understand why it does not print the String.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't print the string? Do you also get garbage? I don't know why my code worked when I posted it, but the `string` variable was too small to hold 2 bytes for the number and 10 bytes of salt plus 1 byte for the null character (was 12 should be at least 13). Now it works as it should.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
With the change you made it still left without printing correctly, I made a change in (char hash_string [66];), you had placed 65.
Now you're doing what I wanted.

Comment: I found another mistake I made. `string[size*2+1] = 0;` should be `string[size*2] = 0;` inside `bytes_to_hexstr`. This should make it work with `char hash_string [65];`.

Comment: If my post answered your question, you should accept it.

Comment: It would be possible to put a counter to concatenate with the String, it would look like this: "Value + Salt + Counter". With this string that would be generated the hash will work. This counter is from 0 to 99.